# How to do hex calculations across multiple cells in excel?

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007, formatting, cells, hexadecimal

I'm working on a spread sheet and I have a table or grid of `[256]x[256]` that looks like this:

```
     B      c   D     E      F    G                     IY
3  Address:   [byte][byte][byte][byte]    ...          [256]
4  0x100000  
5  0x100400
6  0x100800
7  0x100C00
.
.
.
259
```

This table has the following custom format `"0x"@`.

Now I'm trying to do calculations... I'm trying to calculate the address values going vertically down in column `B`.

Instead of manually typing in each value into `B5`, `B6` ... `BN` I'm trying to increment it by `0x400` each time we go down one row...

One would think for cell `B5` they would use something like `=SUM(HEX2DEC(B4),1024)` since `B4` is displayed as hex convert `0x100000` to decimal then add `1024` since `1024` in decimal is `0x400` in hex.

However, Excel is printing the text `0x=Sum(HEX2DEC(B4),1024))` in the cell.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I'm expecting to get `0x100400` as my printed result.

I've tried various combinations of formulas and nothing seems to work, however, if I do something simple like set cell `D4` equal to `B4` using the formula `=B4` in cell `D4`, Excell will display `0x100000` in cell `D4`.

When I try to use any other formula, I'm not getting values in hex...

Even when I try:

```
`=Sum(B4,1024)` in `B5`
```

it still displays

```
`0x=Sum(B4,1024)` in `B5`
```

and when I try:

```
`=Sum(B4,0x400)` in `B5`
```

again it displays

```
`0x=Sum(B4,0x400)` in `B5`...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the formula:

```
="0x" & DEC2HEX(SUM(HEX2DEC(MID(B2,3,10)), HEX2DEC(400)))
```

It get extract the part of B2 after `0x`, convert it to decimal. Add it to converted 400 to decimal. Then convert the result back to hex before concatenating it with `0x`.

[image: IMG:]

Comment: It sort of works, but I'm not getting `0x100400` in cell `B5` I'm getting `0x400`, then `0x800`, etc... It's giving me `0x400` and increments that all the way down, but it's not adding the `0x400` to the `0x100000` from the starting cell...

Comment: @FrancisCugler I see, it 's because the cells were still formatted as "General" instead of "0x"@ as yours

Comment: No problem... I've used excel enough to know some of the basic formulas, but never used it to do calculations in hex...

Comment: So do I need to change the formula or the formatting?

Comment: @FrancisCugler If you change the formatting of the cell to General and enter the first number in B3 as 0x100000, then It should work as mine. But if the requirement is to keep the "0x"@ format, then I need t make change to  my formula.

Comment: I changed the formatting to general but I'm still getting `0x400`, `0x800`....

Comment: I think I got it now... I had to make the entire columns format as general for your formula to work...

Comment: @FrancisCugler I am still intrigued about the "0x"@ format and how to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

I think it has to do with excel seeing it as a string before a function.
In that way the formatting wins over the function calculation.

If you do =TEXT(DEC2HEX(SUM(HEX2DEC(B4),1024)),"0")
it works in my test.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is almost certainly in the cell with the results having the format of "0x"@.

The poster is using Excel 2007 and I cannot test in that. However, we are all used to seeing various formulas entered in a cell with General formatting and after pressing `Enter` seeing the result appear along with the formatting of the referenced cell/s. When possible for Excel to decide. Since only one cell is being referenced here, it can.

Today (2021) using Office 365, I have no difficulties with that happening for this exact situation because... it doesn't. But maybe it would in Excel 2007.

However, there is a related, but more likely possibility:  That the output cell is formatted directly for "0x"@.

Note that the result of the formula is a string (all non-decimals in Excel are actually text strings). So it fits neatly into the format... Excel might simply be taking the string entered, even though it begins with an "=", and handling it as a string, fitting it into the format for a string of "0x"@.

Giving EXACTLY the result shown.

When I enter the formula in a General formatted cell, as mentioned above, it works great. Entering it to edit, then saving the (non-) edit works just fine. But if I format the cell beforehand, it fails to give a good result, instead ending up EXACTLY as reported here.

So while the first possibility mentioned could be it, the second definitively does what is seen. Accordingly, that must (you know, to a high degree of certainty anyway) be it.

(The main objection would be along the lines of "Oh no, Excel always treats something started with an '=' as a formula" but that is shown to not be the case with the actual situation, not even simply a listing of times it likely would not treat it as a formula.)

How to solve? Just return the output column to General formatting so a formula will work and then, since there is no loss in doing so as the output will already be a string, not a number, wrap it with a `TEXT()` using the format. If the value in the result cell needs used further, wrap its reference with a `RIGHT()` that fits the circumstances (probably needs `LEN()` in it, but all the addresses are the same length, one could hard code the `RIGHT()`. Pass its result into whatever formula is using the reference.